# Plotting spectral curves of a pixel in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I click on a pixel, I want to see the spectral plot of that pixel in different bands. I use this code to click on the pixel:

```js
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
          .filterDate('2018-07-01', '2018-9-01')
          .mean()

Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')
Map.onClick(mapClick)

function mapClick(coord){
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coord.lon, coord.lat)
  // Here I want to draw a line graph of a digital pixel number based on wavelength
}
```

In fact, like the Google Earth Engine Inspector, I want to draw a chart
like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance use `reduceRegion()` to get the values for your point, and `ui.Chart.feature.byProperty()` to chart it:

```
var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2018-07-01', '2018-09-01')
  .mean()

Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair')
Map.onClick(mapClick)

function mapClick(coord){
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coord.lon, coord.lat)
  print(spectralCurveChart(image, point))
}

function spectralCurveChart(image, region) {
  var bands = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11']
  var dict = image
    .select(bands)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.first(), 
      geometry: region,
      scale: 30
    })
    
  return ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
    features: ee.Feature(region, dict), 
    xProperties: bands
  })
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/171f18043f8ad2fb4ecdbd7757076860